# I cannot find scikit-learn docs in the installed folder

Tags: scikit-learn

I have installed scikit-learn using pip install, however, I don't see the doc folder there to see the examples and tutorials . Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Be more specific, where are you looking? Try to provide more detail or no one will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The best place to find the most updated and detailed information is the scikit-learn website.

**scikit-learn documentation:** http://scikit-learn.org/stable/documentation.html

**scikit-learn tutorials:** http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/index.html